# download entire photo library phonegap

Tags: cordova, amazon-s3

intelligent people! Noob here!

I am trying to create an app that backs up the entire photo library to a private s3 user bucket with custom encryption and stuff. I have the majority of the code figured out, but I cant seem to figure out how to upload every image in the photo library to the server (similar to the way Google Photos does this) without selecting each individual image. I can find stuff on selecting an image from the gallery, but not on the whole thing.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I've tried for and while loops but it just keeps popping up with the "select image" thing

Comment: paste some code bro

Answer (score 0):

With what I understood from your issue you could consider the following process: 
- List the file available in user Library
- Put the file entry url for each picture in an array
- Loop your upload using cordova-file-transfer

But I'm not sure how much iOs expose the Library folder to be listed as single file.
For Android, check this options which try to [achieve](http://nightlycoding.com/index.php/2015/06/phonegapcordova-read-images-from-gallery-folder-tip/) what you want.

Comment: Okay thank you. I just couldn't figure out a way to do this. I got it now.